# Getting error index of bound while creating getter and setter in sts 3.9.5

Tags: spring-boot

I am using STS 3.9.5 version with JDk 1.8.
While creating getter and setter of a class field i am facing error related to index out of bound.
Kindly suggest how to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran  into this same error on STS4. Since I had many projects open within the same workspace, I decided to first close all the projects, except the current one and another reference project (File -> Close Project for each of the projects to close). Then I closed the STS too. On reopening the STS and the erroring project, I tried to generate the getters and setters in the regular way (right click -> source -> generate Getters and Setters) and it worked fine.
I guess having many SpringBoot projects open with the corresponding embedded Tomcat servers running, it could have caused the error; but I am just guessing. Anyway, without resorting various ways offered, I was able to quickly get over the error.